# numbering the contents of listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with custom adapter which displays names from the contacts . currently its displaying them as

> Rohit
>   Rahul
>   ....

I want it to be like

> 1. Rohit
> 2. Rahul 
>      ....

i.e, number should be appended automatically . I tried doing that using a count variable in both bindview() & newview() method but it gets messed up when i scroll down and come back

the way I am setting text is

```
name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
contactName.setText(count + ". " + name);
```

Comment: are u suing baseadapter?

Comment: What is `count` variable?

Comment: @sinisha count is the one which I am using to add the number to text I am displaying

Comment: @skygeek I am extending cursor adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
contactName.setText(cursor.getPosition() + ". " + name);
```

Comment: Good solution.  Also be aware that [getPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getPosition%28%29) is zero-based, so if you want the list to start at 1 rather than 0, use cursor.getPosition() + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try :`long count = cursor.getPosition();`

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine for what you need:

```
public class CustomCursoAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    public CustomCursoAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
            int count =cursor.getPosition()+1;
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view;
            TextView tv = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.serial_no);
            tv.setText(""+count);
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the position from Cursor by using

```
long count = cursor.getPosition();
```

Then

```
name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
contactName.setText(cursor.getPosition() + ". " + name);
```